# Proof of nomalization condition for a Derived Density Function and its associated CDF expression

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, dirac-delta, cumulative-distribution-functions

I encountered a knowledge gap while attempting to solve a problem I posed to myself. I have presented the problem along with my reasoning below.

Let $G$, $Q$ and $\Theta$ be 3 random variables such that $g= f(\theta,q)$ where $f$ is a real-valued function. If $Q \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu;\sigma^2)$ and $\Theta \sim \mathcal{B}(1,p)$, we can write that:
$$
    N(q) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} exp\bigl\{-\frac{(q-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigr\}
$$

where $N(q)$ is the density function of $Q$.

And,
$$
    B(\theta) = p\delta(\theta-1) + (1-p) \delta(\theta)
$$
where $B(\theta)$ is the density function of $\Theta$.

Thus, the density function of $G$ can be expressed as:
$$
    f_G (g) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta(g-f(\theta,q))N(q)B(\theta) dq d\theta
$$
Integrating first over $\theta$ gives:
\begin{equation*}
    f_G (g) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} p \delta(g-f(1,q))N(q) dq + \int_{\mathbb{R}}(1-p) \delta(g-f(0,q))N(q) dq 
\end{equation*}

Finally, integrating over $q$, using the sifting property of the Dirac delta function, gives:
$$
 f_G (g) = p \sum_i \frac{N(q_i)}{\Bigl\lvert \left. \frac{\partial f(\theta, q)}{\partial q} \right|_{\theta=1, q_i}\Bigr\rvert} + (1-p)  \sum_i \frac{N(q_i)}{\Bigl\lvert \left. \frac{\partial f(\theta, q)}{\partial q} \right|_{\theta=0, q_i}\Bigr\rvert}
$$

where the $q_i$'s corresponds are solutions to $g-f(\theta,q) = 0$ for $\theta = 1$ in the first summation and for $\theta = 0$ in the second summation.
Obviously, $f_G$ is a density function therefore:
$$
    \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_G(g)dg = 1
$$

**Albeit the use of the word "Obviously", I fail to properly prove the previous assumption. Moreover, I would like to be able to express the CDF of this random variable.**

Please feel free to correct my wordings as it may not be rigorous enough. Looking forward to any insights, one can provide.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By paying more attention to the equation, I was able to come up with solution.

Indeed, from the equation obtained previously by integrating over $\theta$, we have that:

$$
         \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_G(g)dg =  p \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}  \delta(g-f(1,q))N(q) dq dg  + (1-p) \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta(g-f(0,q))N(q) dq dg
$$

Since $q$ is fixed when integrating over $g$, it simplifies to :
$$
         \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_G(g)dg =  p \int_{\mathbb{R}}N(q) dq   + (1-p) \int_{\mathbb{R}} N(q) dq 
$$
The end of the proof of the normalization condition follows naturally from the normalization condition of the density functions of $Q$ and $\Theta$.

From this simple calculation, we can provide the CDF of the above PDF.

Let $F_G(g)$ being the CDF of $G$, i.e. $F_G(g) = \int_{-\infty}^{g} f_G(g_0)dg_0$.

In a similar fashion to the proof of the normalization condition, we have that:
$$
        F_G(g) =  p \int_{\mathbb{R}}\Bigl\{\int_{-\infty}^{g}  \delta(g_0-f(1,q))dg_0\Bigr\}N(q) dq   + (1-p) \int_{\mathbb{R}}\Bigl\{\int_{-\infty}^{g} \delta(g_0-f(0,q)) dg_0\Bigr\}N(q) dq
$$

Using the fact that:
$$
        \int_{-\infty}^{t} \delta(x-a) dx = \mathcal{H}(t-a)
$$

where $\mathcal{H}(x)$ is the Heaviside function defined as:
$$
         \mathcal{H}(x) = \begin{cases}
                            0 & \text{if } x < 0 \\
                            1 & \text{if } x \geq 0
                            \end{cases}
$$

Thus, we get:
$$
        F_G(g) =  p \int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathcal{H}(g-f(1,q))N(q) dq   + (1-p) \int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathcal{H}(g-f(0,q))N(q) dq
$$

Therefore:
$$
        F_G(g) =  p \int_{\{q \mid g-f(1,q) \geq 0\}}\mathcal N(q) dq  
        + (1-p) \int_{\{q \mid g-f(0,q) \geq 0\}} N(q) dq
$$

**Hoping that my naïve question would be of assistance to someone else pondering the same issue as I did.**